# Serverless Lambda Authorizer not invoked when deployed to AWS

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, lambda-authorizer

Using serverless, I have deployed an API Gateway with several lambda functions in Node.js. I have also added authentication to one GET endpoint with a lambda authorizor (authenticate.js). I'm out of ideas so any help would be appreciated. The only thing I can see is there is no Lambda Invoke Role assigned to the authorizer. I did not find any docs on how to add that to the serverless yaml, but the Cloudwatch logs dont show any authorizer executions, so I'd expect a 403 or something.

1. Testing locally with serverless offline works just fine
2. Testing locally with Postman works just fine
3. After deploying, testing the lambdas in AWS console works just fine
4. After deploying, testing the API Gateway method in AWS console works just fine
5. After deploying, testing the authenticate.js Lambda authorizer works just fine
6. After deploying, testing the endpoints in Postman fails and returns the following error:

```
<HEAD>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <H1>403 ERROR</H1>
    <H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
    <HR noshade size="1px">
    Bad request.
    We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a
    configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
    <BR clear="all">
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
    <BR clear="all">
    <HR noshade size="1px">
    <PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: yx1B1i6k_J1nqf_jPMTN4AyHD8gKE85KajxhcosOMUZ-tHWoU1E54w==
</PRE>
    <ADDRESS>
    </ADDRESS>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

**serverless.yaml:**

```
functions:
  authenticate:
    handler: src/handlers/auth.authenticate

  list:
    handler: src/handlers/api.list
      events:
        - http:
            path: todos
            method: get
            cors: true
            authorizer: authenticate
```

**Lambda Authorizer:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which endpoint are you trying to hit? Is it a CloudFront URL or the API Gateway default stage URL?

Comment: @SurajBhatia It is a default API Gateway Stage url. I do not have cloudfront setup

Comment: In that case I guess you have an EDGE type API. The error you are getting indicates the request didn't reach your API (was rejected by the CloudFront in front of your EDGE API), so Lambda authorizer would not be invoked. Could you disable authorization on your API and do a simple curl to the API Gateway stage URL?